# Flexslider infinite loop and create("clones") > 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop, flexslider

Here is an example of infinite loop with flexslider:

http://jsfiddle.net/U2Ysh/161/

Problem is it clones only the first image at the end.
If you click through the slides you'll have to reach exactly the end before the show starts from the beginning.

Is there a solution to fire those image clones a couple of slides before to avoid the ugly white gap? Or something else to achieve this? Thx alot.

```
 $('.flexslider.banners').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true,
        controlNav: false,
        slideshow: false,
        smoothHeight: true,
        variableImageWidth: true,
```